# HTML+CSS+JS. Работа с canvas не сохраняет изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function testDrawing(){
        var example = document.getElementById('example');
        var ctx = example.getContext('2d');
        var pic = new Image();
      
    example.width = 3627;
    example.height = 2600;
    pic.src = 'face.png' ;
    
         pic.onload = function() {  
        ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0);

var f = document.getElementById('id1').value;
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.font = "bold 80px segoe script";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText(f, 1200, 1100);

}}

 
function getImage(example){
    var imageData = example.toDataURL();
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageData;
    return image;
}
 
function saveImage(image) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
 
    link.setAttribute("href", image.src);
    link.setAttribute("download", "canvasImage");
    link.click();
}
 
testDrawing();
 
function saveCanvasAsImageFile(){
    var image = getImage(document.getElementById("example"));
    saveImage(image);
}


</script>

 <body>

<div class="okno">
    <input class="edit" id="id1" maxlength="125" size="40" type="text" value="Фио" /> 
    <button class="btn" onclick="testDrawing()">создать</button></div>
<button class="btn2" onclick="saveCanvasAsImageFile()">сохранить</button></div>
<canvas  id='example' style="width: 758px; height: 520px; "> Обновите браузер</canvas>
 </body>
```

По итогу получается следующее Если просто порисовать без вставки изображения картинка сохраняется а если добавить картинку на фон то кнопка не срабатывает друзья нужно срочно помощь всем спасибо кто поможет.

Comment: готов платить за решение

Comment: У вас ошибка в примере *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null*. Так задумано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код в целом рабочий, можете посмотреть пример.
https://jsfiddle.net/m9dnk148/

Возможно, канвас с картинкой не сохраняется из-за CORS, то есть если вы получаете картинку из стороннего источника.

```js
function testDrawing() {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
  var ctx = example.getContext('2d');
  var pic = new Image();

  example.width = 3627;
  example.height = 2600;
  pic.src = `data:image/png;base64,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`;

  pic.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0);
    var f = document.getElementById('id1').value;
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.font = "bold 80px segoe script";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(f, 1200, 1100);


  }
}


function getImage(example) {
  var imageData = example.toDataURL();
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = imageData;
  return image;
}

function saveImage(image) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = image.src;
  link.download = "canvasImage";
  link.click();
}


function saveCanvasAsImageFile() {
  var image = getImage(document.getElementById("example"));
  saveImage(image);
}
```

```html
<input class="edit" id="id1" maxlength="125" size="40" type="text" value="Фио" />
<button class="btn" onclick="testDrawing()">создать</button>
<button class="btn2" onclick="saveCanvasAsImageFile()">сохранить</button>
<canvas id='example' style="width: 758px; height: 520px; "> Обновите браузер</canvas>
```

Comment: Код картинки очень большой получается и редактор на сайте его не может схавать. нужно видимо в скрипте сделать преобразование в base64. как правильно воспользоваться данной библиотекой base64.js

Comment: @ВладимирСергеев не очень понял ваш комментарий, размер картинки не при чем